# Counting words in a column regarding to other column

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: table]

Let's say I have a sheet in this format. I want to count both Man's and Woman's answers to get a percentage. Example pseudocode:

```
for i in range table size
  if Ai equals M and Bi equals T
    add it to man result
  else if Ai equals W and Bi equals T
    add it to woman result
  else
   continue
```

How can I do this with Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with `COUNTIFS` function in Excel:

`=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$15,D1,$B$2:$B$15,"T")`

[image]